# Wordpress random thumbnail SIZE?

Tags: wordpress, image, random, image-size

I'm getting a thumbnail like this in Wordpress:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
```

Now there is 'thumbnail' size but also 'medium', 'large' and 'full'.

How do I get the php code to display these size random? So sometimes there 'small' then 'thumbnail' and then 'full'.

Comment: So you want to randomly display the images different sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested, but something like this should work (assuming I've understood your question):

```
<?php
$sizes = array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'full');
$index = array_rand($sizes);
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, $sizes[$index]);
?>
```

Comment: Nice! Fast and accurate. Thanks!

Comment: No problem; glad to help.  Though it got more accurate when I edited it (I had thought array_rand() returned the element, not the index :| ).